# Meteor: How to serve a static html file

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Im using Meteor with IRON router and it's working great for dynamic files.
But I have one statis legend.html file which I want to serve.
I placed it in the public folder, but I get the error that the file can't be found.

As it has been generated from word, I'm unable to use a template as wrapper.

What is the trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put the static html-file in public folder,
exclude /public from the url:

http://yourdomain.com/yourfile.html

not

http://yourdomain.com/public/yourfile.html

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but seems I have made a mistake, because this works.